About two point Taylor series expansion II
Following the interesting About two point Taylor series expansion problem of finding Taylor expansions around two points, the formulas of  López/Temme partially work with some functions. However, with more complex functions, I have encountered poor representations due to the appearance of poles, as the derivatives of the general formula result in indeterminate forms. Using the formulas presented in the post above (he function aLTTerm by Michael E2), I have obtained some examples.
Zeta[x] result Indeterminate how it could be obtained ??

"I have encountered poor representations due to the appearance of poles, as the derivatives of the general formula result in indeterminate forms" At what points are you trying to evaluate the series? If it's at poles of 1 - Zeta[x], then you'll need to compute the corresponding two-point Laurent expansion around those points, in which case you'll have to compute contour integrals in order to compute the expansion coefficients, rather than compute derivatives.

@march With the formula of López and Tamméz, the result leads to indeterminacy.

Which formula? And have you tried this on simpler functions first to ensure that it's giving you what you expect? I'm coding up a version of Eqs. (3) and (12) from that paper and will be testing on it, but I think you need to include more information in your post in order for us to be able to answer it.

For instance, using the code from the linked answer by Michael E implementing the Lopez/Tammez formulas, I do twoPtTaylor[1 - Zeta[x], {x, -5, 5}, 10] // N; Plot[{1 - Zeta[x], %}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}] leads to this, which sure seems fine.

Sorry @march  the function is Zeta[x] no 1-Zeta[x] I edit the post anyway it is a poor representation omit the pole at 1 that with the formula of twoPtTaylor

I seem to not be getting my point across.  About which points do you want to do the Taylor expansion?  The code above works perfectly fine if you avoid the pole at $z=1$. However, if you want one of the points that you need to expand around be the pole at x=1$, then you'll of course get ComplexInfinity if you try to use the formula which uses derivatives of the function at the pole. If you want to do that, you'll need to compute the Laurent expansion using the contour integrals directly. Please edit the post to include all the information required to answer your question.

Here's what I get for the zeta-function, expanded about $-5$ and $5$ out to forty terms. It seems pretty good.

@march thanks for your comemts.thanks for the clarifications, as I put in the post I wanted the development in the interval 01 that needs the expansion of Laurent of two points but with the formula it uses it cannot be done, they published the formula of Laurent of two points but they did not put examples and I do not know how to use it

In the paper, you need to implement equation 20, with equations 27-30 giving the expansion coefficients. For Zeta[z], $z=1$ is a pole of order $1$, and so you should set $z_1=1$, $m=1$, $z_2 = 0$, and then code up the coefficients in the usual way using Sum and such. I've done this, but I can't guarantee that I've entered everything correctly. My testing seems to indicate that I'm doing something wrong, because the approximation gets worse as I increase the number of terms, but perhaps this is an asymptotic expansion, so that might make sense.

Here is an implementation of two-point Laurent expansion from the Lopez/Temme paper, where the function is analytic at z2, but the point z1 is a pole of order m.  This is implemented using equations (20) and (27-30) from the paper. It requires you to know the order m of the pole, and of course the pole cannot be an essential singularity.
Clear[d, e, twoPointLaurent, z, z1, z2, m, n, m, k, num]
d[0, 1][f_, {{z1_, m_}, z2_}, z_] := f[z2]/(z2 - z1) - Sum[1/(m - k - 1)! Limit[D[(z - z1)^m f[z], {z, m - k - 1}], z -> z1]/(z2 - z1)^(k + 2), {k, 0, m - 1}]
d[0, 2][f_, {{z1_, m_}, z2_}, z_] := 1/m! Limit[D[(z - z1)^m f[z], {z, m}], z -> z1]/(z1 - z2)
d[n_, 1][f_, {{z1_, m_}, z2_}, z_] := -(-1)^n/n! (Sum[(n + k)!/(k! (m + n - k - 1)!) Limit[D[(z - z1)^m f[z], {z, m + n - k - 1}], z -> z1]/(z2 - z1)^(n + k + 2), {k, 0, m + n - 1}] + n Sum[(n + k - 1)!/(k! (n - k)!) (D[f[z], {z, n - k}] /. z -> z2)/(z1 - z2)^(n + k + 1), {k, 0, n}])
d[n_, 2][f_, {{z1_, m_}, z2_}, z_] := -(-1)^n/n! (n Sum[(n + k - 1)!/(k! (m + n - k)!) Limit[D[(z - z1)^m f[z], {z, m + n - k}], z -> z1]/(z2 - z1)^(n + k + 1), {k, 0, m + n}] + Sum[(n + k)!/(k! (n - k - 1)!) (D[f[z], {z, n - k - 1}] /. z -> z2)/(z1 - z2)^(n + k + 2), {k, 0, n - 1}])
 e[n_][f_, {{z1_, m_}, z2_}, z_] := (-1)^n/n! Sum[(n + k)!/(k! (m - n - k - 1)!) Limit[D[(z - z1)^m f[z], {z, m - n - k - 1}], z -> z1]/(z2 - z1)^(n + k), {k, 0, m - n - 1}]
twoPointLaurent[f_, {{z1_, m_}, z2_}, num_, z_] := Sum[(d[n, 1][f, {{z1, m}, z2}, z] (z - z1) + d[n, 2][f, {{z1, m}, z2}, z] (z - z2)) (z - z1)^n (z - z2)^n, {n, 0, num - 1}] + Sum[e[n][f, {{z1, m}, z2}, z] (z - z2)^n (z - z1)^(-n - 1), {n, 0, num - 1}]

For Zeta[x], we can see that there is a pole of order 1 at $x=1$
Series[Zeta[x], {x, 1, 2}]
(* 1/(x - 1) + EulerGamma - StieltjesGamma[1] (x - 1) + 1/2 StieltjesGamma[2] (x - 1)^2 + SeriesData[x, 1, {}, -1, 3, 1] *)

and we can see that it is analytic at $x=0$:
Zeta[0]
(* -(1/2) *)

Thus, in the code above we'll take f to be Zeta, z1 to be 1, m, to be 1, and z2 to be 0.  The fit is already pretty good at order 1:
twoPointLaurent[Zeta, {{1, 1}, 0}, 1, x] // N;
Plot[{Zeta[x], %}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]


but not as good at higher orders (here, order 10):
twoPointLaurent[Zeta, {{1, 1}, 0}, 10, x] // N;
Plot[{Zeta[x], %}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]

This indicates to me that either (a) I've made some small error in the code somewhere (missed a -1 maybe? who knows?), (b) there's a typo in the paper, or (c) this expansion is actually asymptotic, which means that we won't expect the fit to get arbitrarily better as we increase the order.


Thanks @march  great job

with the function $$\text{twoPointLaurent}\left(\frac{\cos (x+1)}{x-1},{{1,1},0},1,x\right)$$ gives $$x \underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\cos (x+1)}{x-1}(x)+(x-1) \left(\left(-\frac{\cos (x+1)}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{\sin (x+1)}{x-1}\right)(x)+\left(\frac{\cos (x+1)}{x-1}\right)'(x)\right)\right)+\frac{\underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}(x-1) \frac{\cos (x+1)}{x-1}(x)}{x-1}+(x-1) \left(-\underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}(x-1) \frac{\cos (x+1)}{x-1}(x)-\frac{\cos (x+1)}{x-1}(0)\right)$$

and it should be $$(z-1) z^2 \sin (1)-z^2 \sin (1)+2 (z-1) z^2 \sin (2)-z^2 \sin (2)-3 (z-1) z^2 \cos (1)+2 z^2 \cos (1)+\frac{5}{2} (z-1) z^2 \cos (2)-2 z^2 \cos (2)+z \sin (1)-z \cos (1)+\frac{z \cos (2)}{z-1}+z \cos (2)-\frac{z \cos (1)}{z-1}+\frac{\cos (1)}{z-1}$$ in code(Cos[1]/(-1 + z) - zCos[1] - (zCos[1])/(-1 + z) + 2z^2Cos[1] -
3*(-1 + z)z^2Cos[1] + zCos[2] + (zCos[2])/(-1 + z) -
2z^2Cos[2] +
(5/2)(-1 + z)z^2Cos[2] + zSin[1] -
z^2Sin[1] + (-1 + z)z^2Sin[1] - z^2Sin[2] + 2*(-1 + z)z^2Sin[2])

and with double pole twoPointLaurent[Zeta[x]^2, {{1, 2}, 0}, 1, x] gives $$\frac{\underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}\left(\left(\left(\zeta (x)^2\right)'(x)+\left(2 \zeta (x) \zeta '(x)\right)(x)\right) (x-1)^2+2 \zeta (x)^2(x) (x-1)\right)-\underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}(x-1)^2 \zeta (x)^2(x)}{x-1}... $$ and it do not work and it is should be:$$\frac{6 \gamma  x^2}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{9 x^2}{4 (x-1)^2}+\frac{\gamma ^2 x}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{4 \gamma  x}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{9 x}{4 (x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{4 (x-1)^2}...$$

@capea You need to enter the function as either a pure function or the name of a function. Thus, if you want to do Zeta[x]^2, you need to either define g[x_] = Zeta[x]^2 and then do something like twoPointLaurent[g, {{1, 1}, 0}, 10, x] or do twoPointLaurent[Zeta[#]^2 &, {{1, 1}, 0}, 10, x].

Thanks @mar  for the clarification but if I use the function Clear[f]
f[x_] := 1/Zeta[x]
L1 = twoPointLaurent[f, {{-2, 1}, 1}, 2, x] , 1/zeta[0] ==1 is analitic in x=1 at it has a pole in x=-2 and gives indertermination
